# A list of situations where there is no need to specify the person with his, her or their and etc

Tags: reflexivos

I know already several of these situations but I start seeing more in my textbook, so I think there is a chance there is a lot more.

*can someone please give a fullest list possible of these situations*

What I know include

> when reflexive verbs are use like levantarse, cepillarse. For example, cepillarse el pelo, not su or mi pelo.

Another example, I can't explain exactly why:

> se levanta temeroso de que se le caiga el techo en la cabeza.

Comment: I don't know if somebody give you **the** fullest list possible of these situations (or if that kind of question is even on-topic here), but if I were you, I would start leading the way with whatever research you have already. I think that you could create a community-wiki type answer and let other users contribute with whichever cases they know. Thus said, probably you'll be luckier if you go to text books or learning resources, instead of a Q&A type site like this.

Comment: How to make a community wiki type answer?

Comment: The problem is it is not on textbook. The list. I did Google it but saw none

Comment: When typing your answer just mark the "community wiki" checkbox on the bottom right corner under the text box for the answer. Please, understand that this is only my suggestion and moderators could still have something to say about the best way to address this situation. Maybe there is no need for community wiki at all (I have been wrong before). Maybe they'll understand this question as "too board" for the format of this site.

Comment: I will do what I can to get the question to stay unclosed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. Maybe the problem is that you need an appropriate question so then you could easily find the answer in a book or on Internet. (I remember the great book "The hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy"...)

But maybe I can help you anyway. I'll write in spanish because I express myself better in that way.

Voy a intentar reformular tu pregunta: ¿Preguntas en qué casos, cuando en inglés se usa un determinante posesivo en un sintagma nominal, en el contexto de una oración, en español no es necesario y normalmente no lo ponemos?

Si es así, pondré ejemplos primero y luego expndré el análisis.

(1)

> Me lavo los dientes.
>
> *I brush my teeth.*

(2)

> ¿Me prestas tu bolígrafo?
>
> *Can I borrow your pen?*

(3)

> ¡Le ha robado la cartera!
>
> *He stole his wallet!*

Creo que podemos establecer un patrón sin necesidad de hacer una lista.

El caso que tú conoces es el de los verbos reflexivos<sup>1</sup>, pero eso es un caso particular. Son el caso en que el sujeto y el complemento directo (CD) o indirecto (CI) coinciden (el sujeto ejerce la acción sobre sí mismo). El *se* en esos casos son el complemento directo o indirecto. Un ejemplo:

> Me cepillo los dientes.

Sujeto: yo. CD: los dientes. CI: me.

> Me peino.

Sujeto: yo. CD: me.

El caso general: En los ejemplos (1) y (3) elidimos los determinantes posesivos (*my*, *his*) porque el pronombre personal de CI que hay en cada oración nos indica que la acción recae en esa persona, y sobreentendemos que los dientes (ejemplo (1)) son de la persona a la que alude el pronombre (es el caso reflexivo), o que la cartera (ejemplo (3)) es de la persona a la que han robado (nuevamente nos lo indica el pronombre). Si viéramos escrito -cosa rara-:

(4)

> Le cepillo los dientes.

querría decir que el sujeto estaría cepillando los dientes a la persona a la que alude el *le*, probablemente un niño pequeño que no sabe hacerlo por sí mismo. Lo mismo con:

(5)

> Átate los cordones de los zapatos.

Los zapatos son tuyos porque así nos lo indica el *te*.

Además en todos estos casos el objeto es algo muy personal: normalmente uno no va a cepillar los dientes a otro, no va a atar los cordones a otro y tampoco va a llevar encima la cartera de otro.

En el ejemplo (2) indicamos el determinante posesivo *tu* de *tu bolígrafo* porque podría ser que le pidiéramos el bolígrafo de otra persona:

> ¿Me prestas el bolígrafo de tu hermana?

En conclusión: Depende de la relación con el objeto, entenderemos de quién es mediante el pronombre o necesitaremos añadir un posesivo. Si, como en los dientes, normalmente no se los cepillamos a otro, el pronombre nos lo dirá; si, como en el bolígrafo, puede ser de otra persona, lo especificamos mediante el posesivo.

Espero que mi respuesta te ayude, no sé si era esto lo que buscabas.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ahora mismo no recuerdo con exactitud la definición de verbo relexivo, pero llamémoslos así ahora.

---

EDIT:

Sin embargo, volviendo al ejemplo del bolígrafo, al decir:

> Me ha robado el bolígrafo.

se sobreentendería que el bolígrafo es mío (o estaba en mi posesión enel momento del robo). Podríamos decir:

> Me ha robado mi bolígrafo.

pero eso sería sólo para enfatizar que el bolígrafo es mío. Si te roban el coche, lo más normal es decir:

> Ayer me robaron el coche.

En ninguno de estos casos usaríamos la fórmula:

> Ayer robaron mi coche.

que es correcta pero inusual en lenguaje coloquial. En todos estos casos usamos el CI y, así, sobreendemos el posesivo y decimos *el coche* en lugar de *mi coche*.

Por contra, en lenguaje formal (periódicos...) tenemos:

> Robaron el coche del presidente.

y no:

> Le robaron el coche al presidente.

Así que siempre que un ponombre personal nos indique de quién es el objeto no pondremos un determinante posesivo.

La siguiente cuestión será: ¿cuándo hay necesidad de poner un pronombre de CI para estos casos? Por el momento sólo puedo decir que con el uso uno lo va aprendiendo.

Comment: Estuve mucho rato pensando cómo responder esta pregunta tan amplia y finalmente me di por vencido (probablemente les pasó a otros también). Está muy completo, buen trabajo. +1.

Comment: Coincido con Rodrigo. Sugerí al OP hacer una respuesta community wiki porque pensaba que era demasiado trabajo para una sola persona/respuesta compilar una lista de este estilo. Paloma me ha dejado impresionado por la cantidad de trabajo que le ha metido a este post. Mi +1 también. Muy merecido, he de decir.