# "en nuestro cerebro" plural noun or singular

Tags: gramática, plurales

I want to ask a question about when to pluralise a noun in specific context.

I was writing an essay in Spanish about what the world would be like in 30 years and I wanted to say that computers could be implanted in our heads.

I used the futuro imperfecto for this and thought it would appear as such:

> Serán implantados en nuestro cerebro

but I was thinking, in English, we would say

> in our **brains**

but in Spanish, it appears from the examples I have found, this is not the case so it says as "cerebro".

How is this sentence translated?

Comment: This is easier to decide about in Spanish than in English, thanks to the pattern "Me lavo los dientes" (rather than "Me lavo mis dientes").  Here's the canonical Q-A for this topic: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26171/9385.  You could also take a look at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10794/9385.

Comment: * I meant to say: thanks to te pattern "Me lavo los diente" (rather than "Lavo mis dientes").

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments, we would normally use a [possessive dative](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26171/24236) to write this. Most naturally, we would also avoid the passive voice:

- Nos implantarán ordenadores en el cerebro
- Se nos implantarán ordenadores en el cerebro

where *nos* is the possessive dative, and the use of *se* is called [pasiva refleja](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32674/24236), which is a more natural way to write these passive sentences. If you do want to write the sentence in pure passive form, you would say

- Nos serán implantados ordenadores en el cerebro

Regarding your "other" question about plurals, [both forms are correct](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/465860683805257728?lang=en):

- Nuestro cerebro podrá comunicarse con estos ordenadores
- Nuestros cerebros podrán comunicarse con estos ordenadores

Comment: About the part at the beginning about the alternatives to the passive voice -- this is interesting and I'm glad you included it even though it's a tiny bit tangential.  Do you want to add an explanation of "Nos implantarán" too -- something about, I'm not sure what to call it, maybe the impersonal "they"? // Do you think that one or the other of the last two bullets is more common or natural than the other?